# SQL - calculate repeat purchase probability

Tags: sql, sql-server, statistics

I want to calculate repeat purchase probability based on the following example. I want to run this calculation on SQL and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

Example:

- Amount of customers who placed 1 order: 1,000
- Amount of customers who placed 2 orders: 350
- Amount of customers who place 3 orders: 130

In this example, the repeat order probability of customers who have placed one order in their lifetime to placing a second order is: (350 + 130) / (350+130+1,000) = 32.43%

The end result should look like this:

[image]

And so on...

Thanks!

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And please explain where you are stuck... showing your current query would be a start.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation we want is total minus running_total divided by running_total in the other direction.

```
select  *
       ,cast(100*(1.0*sum(order_total) over()-sum(order_total) over(order by "order"))/sum(order_total) over(order by "order" desc) as decimal(10,2)) as repeat_purchase_prob
from    t
order by "order"
```

| order | order_total | repeat_purchase_prob |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 32.43 |
| 2 | 350 | 27.08 |
| 3 | 130 | 0.00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MIR-VRpo)